# jQuery.post json data received with unexpected name in server

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I've an issue with some javascript - knockout code when I submit my json data with jQuery.post:

I'm using C# MVC3 and I have an action with a Model as input parameter. I'm retrieving from the web client one of my KO objects in form of JSON and submitting it with ajax:

```
$.post("MyAction", ko.toJS(myObject));
```

I suppose to receive all my data in the Request.Form variable at the server, but myObject has two nested lists inside and I'm receiving data with names as follows:

```
varname1 -> it's ok
list[0][varname2] -> list[0] is OK, but I'm expecting list[0].varname2...
```

I'm searching through the jQuery (version 1.8.3, quite old, I know...) code but I can't see where the code is encoding the param names.

In my JSON, they are correct:

```
{ varname1: "somedata", list: [{varname2: "some data", varname3:"and some more"}] }
```

I'm peeking in my request with firebug and I see the wrong names sended to the server, so I'm quite sure the problem is in the javascript code.

I'm trying to guess how can I get the correct names...

Can you give me a hand, please?

Thanks to all in advance.

Kind regards.

Comment: What do you mean by `list[0][varname2] -> list[0] is OK, but I'm expecting list[0].varname2...`, and can you post the request you inspected with Firebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your json conversion is incorrect.

- You're using $.post("MyAction", **ko.toJS**(myObject));
- You should be using $.post("MyAction", **ko.toJSON**(myObject)); instead

ko.toJS is used to convert json to a js object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, after some days out (holidays), I realize... However, I think browsers should parse JSON object to get the variable names properly... Where is the code used to transform json objects in "form fields" to send to the server?
that code is in jQuery? an external parser / function, or is the browser itself who makes that transform?

It's simple curiosity...

Thanks a lot for your responses.
Regards.